# When to use setState callback argument versus directly passing the value

Tags: reactjs

According to React docs, I found there are two forms of `setState`:

- Form 1: `setState({someState: someValue})`
- Form 2: `setState((preState) => ({someState: doSomething(preState)}))`

Form 1 sets state directly, form 2 sets state by using a callback function.

In the [Using state correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) section, I've been told that form 1 may not be safe. Does this mean I should always to use form 2 to set state correctly? I soon noticed there is [another example here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#equivalent-class-example) which uses form 1 to update state. Is it an incorrect example?

The form 1 and form 2 may both right, but in which situations is it perfectly safe to use form 1, and in which situations should I use form 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a note on `setState`. I hope it will help you to use it properly. If you read it sincerely and understand it, you're gonna be better at using it to manage state.

## setState

It's ***asynchronous***

```
state = { count: 0};
increment() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
    console.log(this.state.count) // 0
}

increment() 
console.log(this.state.count); // 1
```

And, the final value of `this.state.count` will be 1 after completion of the calling `incemenent()`

Because React batch all calls up, and figure out the result and then efficiently make that change. Kind of this pure JavaScript code, merging where the last one wins

```
newState = Object.assign(
    {},
    firstSetStateCall,
    secondSetStateCall,
    thirdSetStateCall,
);
```

So, we can say here everything has to do with JavaScript object merging. So there's another cool way, where we pass a function in  `setState`  instead of object.

```
state = { count: 0};
increment() {
    this.setState( (state) => {  return { count: state.count + 1} } );
    this.setState( (state) => {  return { count: state.count + 1} } );
    this.setState( (state) => {  return { count: state.count + 1} } );
}

increment();
console.log(this.state.count) // 3
```

This time we will get 3 because earlier it was possible to merge objects but it's not possible to merge functions so it works like synchronous.

But another nice application of this method of passing parameters in `this.setState` is you can implement logic before returning the objects from the function

```
this.setState( (state) => { if(state.count === 0) return { count: state.count + 1} } );
```

Not only that, the function we pass inside `setState` takes another parameter,  `props`.

`this.setState((state, props) => { //play here })`

But, the function we're passing it could grow messy by time, so what? Just make a regular JavaScript function

and pass it to the `setState`

`this.setState(fn)`

## If SetState is asynchronous how we can do an operation just after the state gets updated?

`setState` actually takes two arguments, second one of these two is callback function, that is invoked after state is updated,

```
this.setState ( 
    (state, props) => { 
        // code here
    }, 
    () => {console.log("updated state", this.state)}
        
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

The choice of form depends on whether the next state uses the value of the current state.

If the new state relies on the current state, use form 2. Otherwise use form 1.

Comment: but https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#equivalent-class-example rely on the current state and use the #form1

Comment: @gaols their documentation uses that form in that example for the sake of simplicity, not correctness. See [this warning](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Comment: because i see the warning, so i'm confused by that example. for me correctness is more important than simplicity.